# Perl LWP get blocked by server 404 not found

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent

I am using `LWP::UserAgent` to download an csv in unix server

```
my $ua1 = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $res = $ua1->get($equity_history_url, @netscape_like_headers);
```

The server keeps giving me an error with code 404 (not found)

Despite that I can download this file from the browser -> 
http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/18-08-2013-TO-17-08-2015ADANIPOWERALLN.csv

and the code works with other pages

I think the issue is one of the [below](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=251057)

- The site is looking for a cookie.
- The site is decoding the agent string.
- The site is making a decision based on some other part of the
  HTTP request header.

I tried passing a header similar to my browser which I captured using wireshark

```
my @netscape_like_headers = (
    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset' => 'iso-8859-1,*,utf-8',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => '1',
    'Accept' =>     'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
);
```

still no luck. any suggestions?

Comment: When I click that link it directly downloads the file. It cannot be a cookie.

Comment: Why not contact the owners of the web site and ask them how they would like you to download that data from their site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use LWP::UserAgent on that URL without your headers I get a *403 Forbidden* error back. Same with `curl`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $res = $ua->get(
    'http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/18-08-2013-TO-17-08-2015ADANIPOWERALLN.csv');
print $res->as_string;

__END__
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 18 Aug 2015 12:19:13 GMT
Server: AkamaiGHost
Content-Length: 388
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Tue, 18 Aug 2015 12:19:13 GMT
Client-Date: Tue, 18 Aug 2015 12:19:13 GMT
Client-Peer: 104.85.166.76:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Mime-Version: 1.0
Title: Access Denied

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;nseindia&#46;com&#47;content&#47;equities&#47;scripvol&#47;datafiles&#47;18&#45;08&#45;2013&#45;TO&#45;17&#45;08&#45;2015ADANIPOWERALLN&#46;csv" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;48a65568&#46;1439900353&#46;1006096e
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When I added your headers, it worked the first time I tried. When I re-ran it, it also gave *404 Not Found*. Now when I click the link in the browser, it gives a 404 as well.

I believe they are preventing you from dowloading the file multiple times. If you are on a dial-up connection or broadband with a non-static IP address, **try to reconnect to get a fresh one, or use a proxy**.

---

Maybe they also have terms of services that forbid using automation tools to access their ressources because they are not ment to be APIs.

### Update

In fact they do not allow what you are trying to do! Point 12 of [their terms of services](http://nseindia.com/global/content/termsofuse.htm) clearly states that.

> You may not conduct any systematic or automated data collection activities (including scraping, data mining, data extraction and data harvesting) on or in relation to our website without our express written consent.

Answer (score 0):

In general, make your LWP user-agent look like a known browser. You can set the name of the user-agent with a parameter to `new` or set it later:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    agent => ...,
    );

$ua->agent( ... );
```

You can do other things, such as adding a cookie jar. LWP::UserAgent doesn't do that by default. Following a particular path through a website, setting referers, and other human-like behavior sometimes solve the problem. You may want to look at [WWW::Mechanize](http://www.metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize) for that sort of thing.

Some sites will use Javascript to do various things which your basic Perl-based user-agent can't do for you. In those cases, you might use Perl to control a UI-based browser like I show in [Controlling Firefox from Perl](http://perltricks.com/article/138/2014/12/8/Controlling-Firefox-from-Perl).